# When one test case is executed & move to second test case this time test case agin start from login page not start from existing page

Tags: cypress

```
describe('CMS Department', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        // Navigate to the desired URL before each test
        cy.visit('https://whitecode.biz/staging/cms/admin');

        Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
            // returning false here prevents Cypress from
            // failing the test
            return false
        })
      });
      
    it('Add_Dept_Possitive_Scenario', () => {

        cy.fixture('cmslogin').then((data) => {

            const login = new Department();
            login.setEmail(data.email);
            login.setPassword(data.password);
            login.clickSignIn();

        })

        const dept = new Department();
        dept.Open_Dept();
        dept.Add_New_Dept();
        dept.Breadcrum_Image();
        dept.Faculty_Select("1");
        dept.Department_Name("Re-department")
        dept.Show_On_Website();
        dept.Add_Department();
    });

    it('Edit_Department', () => {

        cy.fixture('cmslogin').then((data) => {

            const login = new Department();
            login.setEmail(data.email);
            login.setPassword(data.password);
            login.clickSignIn();

        })

        const dept = new Department();
        dept.Open_Dept();
        dept.Edit_Record();

    })
```

After the first test execution the second test case does not start from existing page it starts again from login page. I expected second test case start from existing page.

Comment: The problem is your expectation, the code's working fine. Test cases should be independent.

Answer (score 5):

The answers given already are not very helpful, just wag a finger and tell you what you cannot do.

Practically, you could use the `cy.session()` command to handle the login state. This command is used to ***recreate a consistent browser context between tests***, [ref](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session).

The usage for your code is something like

```js
describe('CMS Department', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('https://whitecode.biz/staging/cms/admin');

    cy.session(() => {
      cy.fixture('cmslogin').then((data) => {
        const login = new Department();
        login.setEmail(data.email);
        login.setPassword(data.password);
        login.clickSignIn();
      })
    })
  });
      
  it('Add_Dept_Possitive_Scenario', () => {
    const dept = new Department();
    ...
  });

  it('Edit_Department', () => {
    const dept = new Department();
    ...
  })
```

---

You can also get a positive opinion on the issue from this blog [Writing Tests That Depend On Other Tests](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/dependent-test/).

Gleb Bahmutov was one of the main architects of Cypress and is still developing new and practical patterns.

In fact I would go so far as to advise ignoring 90% of the opinions given in this forum (including my own) and search through Gleb's blog initially when you have a Cypress problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

One of Cypress' core concepts is [Test Isolation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation), and by default it is enabled. At a high level, Cypress' Test Isolation means that each test runs from a clean browser state, and does not share any state with tests that run before and after it. While there are ways to disable Test Isolation, I would echo @jonrsharpe's and Cypress's sentiment [that tests should be independent.](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2023/03/08/test-isolation-as-a-best-practice/)